# How do you alter what VS2k10 shows for Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Here's what happened; I was working on some code and assumed (yes, my bad) that the return value would be a Null object, when in fact the returned object is never null, and the success/failure is in a member.

As it turns out the behavior is documented in the XML Comment block on the function I was using, however, VS2k10 doesn't show the `<returns>...</returns>` block, only the `<summary>...</summary>` block.

Is there a way to adjust VS2k10 to show the `<returns>...` comments as well?

Comment: have you tried removing the whole intellisense comment and re-adding it? It should provide you with the correct comment method signature for that method.

Comment: @TheSavage The XML file for that library has the correct information, but VS2k10 doesn't seem to show the `<returns>...` node ever, as a tooltip or when you are coding for that function.

Comment: Weird, have you tried updating your references? Does it show in the object browser?

Comment: @TheSavage Shows in the object browser. This is a DLL project, no option to refresh references. Is it supposed to show as part of intellisense? None of our installations here show it. If you hover over `Object.StaticMethod` you only see the function prototype and `<summary>` no `<returns>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we never show `<returns>` in Quick Info or Parameter Info. You have to view it in Object Browser.

Another alternative is to position the caret on the method name that you want to view `<returns>` for, and hit <kbd>F12</kbd> (or whatever key is mapped to the Go To Definition command, `Edit.GoToDefinition`). This will open "Metadata As Source" window, which will contain the full method signature along all XML documentation comments, including `<returns>`.

Comment: Is there anyway to customize what is shown for Quick Info and/or Parameter Info?